# Navigation Items In Page But Not Displaying WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

During the process of working on my new WordPress site using Humescores as the theme, I noticed that my primary navigation menu stopped displaying. Upon inspection though, one can see that the navigation and li items are indeed in the page. But I cannot get them to render.  I've set the background color of the navigation to red with a yellow border so you can see where it is.  And I've attempted to set the font color to white but you can see none of the links are displaying.  Very wierd behavior.  What gives?

From functions.php

```
register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Header', 'humescores' ),

        ) );
```

From header.php

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" style="border: 2px solid yellow; background-color:red; color:#fff;">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'humescores' ); ?></button>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
            ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

[ChromeDevToolsScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwm5h.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `z-index:99999;` inside the css for the navigation.